# How to create vertex and relationship using jSon in Orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I have my Json as :-

```
{ @class : 'Account',
  name : 'Luca',
  vehicles : [ {
     @class : 'Vehicle',
     type : 'Car',
     model : 'Maserati',
     isItTrue: false
  } ]
 }
```

I want to create an edge( not link )  between account and vehicle. How can I acheive this?
 If not possible by this json format, Can u please provide a json format, using which i can create account and vehicle vertices and relationship between them.
 Thanks.

Comment: Did you tryied oriento https://github.com/codemix/oriento ?

Comment: No i didn't try that, but i read the API provided by oriento, i couldn't find any api which can accept json directly and create vertex and edges, Here also to create the edge we need to parse the json first , and then call                                                                                        db.create('EDGE', 'E')
.from('#12:12')
.to('#12:13')
I needed something like oetl, which accepts json and creates vertices and edges, but yes it works only for importing data .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Waterline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline) and [sails-oreintdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-orientdb) in your project. I am sure you are looking for this approach.

Cheers